# Is there a way to optimize the following insert with PrestoDB?

Tags: regex, amazon-s3, hive, presto

I am running a query that inserts data from a source table to a target table using PrestoDB and AWS S3 (and Glue for the metadata).

The query looks like the following (even though it has many more cases):

```
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT other_field AS other_field ,
       (CASE
            WHEN regexp_like(LOWER(user_agent) , LOWER('bot')) THEN '1'
            WHEN regexp_like(LOWER(user_agent) , LOWER('spider')) THEN '2'
            WHEN regexp_like(LOWER(user_agent) , LOWER('crawler')) THEN '3'
            WHEN regexp_like(LOWER(user_agent) , LOWER('Google-AdSense-Auto')) THEN '4'
            WHEN regexp_like(LOWER(user_agent) , LOWER('Google-Adwords-DisplayAds-WebRender')) THEN '5'
            ELSE NULL
        END) AS bot_type
FROM source_table;
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently? I could not find any resources about this.

Comment: one option is a mapping table with the words and numbers, which can be used to `join` before `insert`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use case-insensitive regexp (add `(?i)`) and get rid of `LOWER()`:

```
WHEN regexp_like(user_agent,'(?i)bot') THEN '1' 
WHEN regexp_like(user_agent,'(?i)spider') THEN '2'
...
```

It will not help much to improve performance because of parallel execution, though case-insensitive regexp looks simpler.

Comment: Thanks! I think what @vamsi was suggesting also works. I elaborate it later.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested by @Vamsi Prabhala

```
WITH
user_agents AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            headers_user_agent
        FROM
            source_table
        WHERE
            YEAR = '2020')
bot_types AS
    (SELECT
      headers_user_agent,
      (CASE
        WHEN regexp_like(LOWER(headers_user_agent), LOWER('bot'))     THEN '2'
        WHEN regexp_like(LOWER(headers_user_agent), LOWER('spider'))  THEN '3'
        ELSE NULL)
        AS
          bot_type
        FROM
          user_agents)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  bot_types
WHERE
  bot_type IS NOT NULL
```

I insert this into a table that I can join to the query and getting rid of the CASE in the other SQL. Since I execute the CASE based SQL once and the other one 100 times per day this is a great improvement.